# In AngularJS, How do I create a custom validation directive that takes a $scope variable and compares it for equality to the ng-model?

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

I'm looking to make a new angular directive which serves the purpose of comparing the input's ngmodel value to some other value, and checking them for equality.

If they are equal, I want this input to be valid.  Otherwise, invalid.

```
<div ng-repeat="one in many">
    <ng-form name="somethingToValidate">
        <input type="text" ng-model="one.userTypedText" 
               required mustbeequalto="one.someOtherValue" />
    </ng-form>
</div>
```

That's an example of the "mustbeequalto" directive in use when it's complete.
1) Please be aware that {{one.someOtherValue}} can change at ANY time, so this directive must be aware of the 2-way binding nature of this value.
2) I will be using this inside an ng-repeat, so it should be smart enough to only work within the scope of the particular ng-form containing it.

I think I need a validation directive, but if you think there is a better/moreelegant way, please advise.  I've tried creating this directive and have failed miserably.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write a function that returns the value of `ng-model`:

```
require: 'ngModel',
link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModelController) {

  var getModelValue = function() {
  return ngModelController.$viewValue;
};
```

As shown above you can retrieve this via `ngModelController.$viewValue`. The `ngModelController` is available as the fourth argument in the link function by requiring it.

Write a function that returns the value of what is passed to the `must-be-equal-to` attribute:

```
var getMustBeEqualToValue = function() {
  return scope.$eval(attributes.mustBeEqualTo);
};
```

You can use the `$eval` method to execute the expression on the current scope to get the correct value.

Write a function that sets the validity:

```
var setValidity = function (isValid) {
  ngModelController.$setValidity('mustBeEqualTo', isValid);
};
```

Use `$watch` to execute `setValidity` everytime the value of `ng-model` changes:

```
scope.$watch(getModelValue, function(newValue, oldValue) {
  if (newValue === oldValue) return;
  setValidity(newValue === getMustBeEqualToValue());
});
```

Use `$watch` to execute `setValidity` everytime the value of what is passed to the `must-be-equal-to` attribute changes:

```
scope.$watch(getMustBeEqualToValue, function(newValue, oldValue) {
  if (newValue === oldValue) return;
  setValidity(getModelValue() === newValue);
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/w9t0uk6l0HL0QYi40Cth?p=preview

There is room for optimizations, but the example should hopefully be a good start.

Comment: Looks like a great answer, i'll test monday and come back.

Comment: @tasseKATT Is there a way to get the value of the variable passed into the validator without using scope.$eval(attributes.mustBeEqualTo);?

Comment: @sneilan You could use the `$parse` service, but that is what `scope.$eval` does internally. If you can explain your use case I can try to help.